# Creating an SQL view with notl null columns from nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a view, and import it into Entity Framework 6.
The following view cannot be imported since both columns are nullable.
(Table and column names were changed, second column is intended for calculating the first of the month from a datetime column)

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.sometext Col1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, b.somedate), 0) Col2
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE a.sometext IS NOT NULL AND b.somedate IS NOT NULL
```

As far as I understand, if both columns were not null, EF will be able to import 
the view. Is it correct?
How can I change the view to make this work?

Comment: Try `ISNULL(a.sometext,'') Col1`. Even though you've limited it to not null records, the underlying column is still nullable.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the resulting expression to be non-nullable.  SQL Server does this with the function `ISNULL()` (although not with `COALESCE()`).  So, you can do:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
    SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(a.sometext, '') as Col1,
           ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(mont, 0, b.somedate), 0), GETDATE()) as Col2
    FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN
         Table2 b
         ON a.Id = b.Id
    WHERE a.sometext IS NOT NULL AND b.somedate IS NOT NULL;
```

`ISNULL()` is non-nullable if any of the arguments are not nullable.  `COALESCE()` requires that all arguments be non-nullable to inherit this attribute.

This is hard to find in the documentation.  Here is an [article](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) that discusses the topic.